# creating a cursor to pull values from a table based on criteria matching to another table

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a cursor statement that will pull values from table A based on when other column values from table A match to table B. For example, I want the ID column values from table A to be pulled when the First and Last Name values from table A match with First and Last Name values from table B. I need this to loop through the whole table. What would be the best way to go about writing the statement?

I tried joining on matching criteria, but table A is so large it took 15 hours to load.

Comment: I guess, sample data and desired output will help us to help you and clarify, if you really need a cursor here

Comment: Please attach some sample data and what you've tried. Obviously, you don't need to attach all the data that took 15 hours to process, but a representative sample and the code should help us figure out if there's a way to optimize the code you have, or if you need a cursor for batching, how to implement it.

Comment: You may be better off asking how to solve the problem that caused to to want a trigger in the first place. Triggers aren't often the best solution to a problem.

Comment: There are better ways than cursors, start with a join to combine the 2 tables.

Comment: Please publish the table definitions so we can see the indexes and an execution plan